# Terminal command to dump the next N lines of a file after a line containing X?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I want to dump the 10 lines of a file after the line containing "THE_WORD".

Is there a clever command line one-liner for this?

The best I can come up with is this but it displays all lines after THE_WORD, not just 10:

```
tail MYFILE -n +`grep -n THE_WORD MYFILE|head -1|sed "s/:.*//"`
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you are looking for `-A` and `-m` options of `grep` command.

```
grep -m1 -A10 PATTERN filename
```

it looks for first occurrence of `PATTERN` (`-m1`) in the file `filename` and includes 10 lines after match into the results.